# Find the minimum value and it's location from the depth images in opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, min

I am working depth data which is in the format of 16UC1. I want to find out the min value (greater than 0) with location from the image. I am using the minMaxLoc function but I am getting the error. It may be because of short values. It will be great , if you suggest the way.

```
  int main()
 {
      Mat abc = imread("depth272.tiff");
      cout << abc.size() << endl;

      imshow("depth_image",abc);
      Mat xyz = abc > 0;
      cout << "abc type: " << abc.type() << "xyz type " << xyz.type() << endl;

      double rmin, rmax;
      Point rMinPoint, pMaxPoint;
      minMaxLoc(abc, &rmin, &rmax, &rMinPoint, &pMaxPoint, xyz);
      int row = rMinPoint.x;
      int col = rMinPoint.y;

   waitKey(0);
   return 0;
```

}

[image]

Comment: Can you paste the full error Traceback ?

Comment: Does it work without the mask?

Comment: @AdiShavit ...I am not using any mask. I have pasted my whole code.

Comment: @ ZdaR ..updated

Comment: `imread` loads by default as `CV_8UC3`. Use `imread(..., IMREAD_UNCHANGED)` to load as `CV_16UC1`

Comment: @SV: Now I see the whole code. Your mask is `xyz`.

Comment: Thank you @Miki ..I have changed. The error is gone but I am getting type of the abc mat is 2 (16UC1) and type of the xyz is 0 (8UC1). It is because of comparison with 0. I need xyz in the form of 16UC1 data only.

Comment: xyz is just a mask. It contains only 0 and 255 values. Why do you need it to be 16UC1?

Comment: @Miki..Thanks a lot. I understood :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is loaded as a 3-channel `8UC3` image.
The function `minMaxLoc()` only works on single channel images.
As @Miki suggests, you should use `imread(..., IMREAD_UNCHANGED)` to load as `CV_16UC1`.